# Restricting table cell resizing in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, resizing, protected

Is it possible to restrict users from resizing the cells of a table in protected documents in MS Word 2010? I want to restrict them from making any changes to the layout of the table (or, at least, to restrict them from changing the width of columns).

I have tried playing with the settings from the restrictions menu, but to no avail...

Comment: Have you tried using a specific table style and then restricting editing to that style?

Comment: How is it protected; track changes, no changes, fill in forms? The only one which allows for table changes is the "track changes" option. The other options for protection should not allow table resizing.

Comment: Basically, as an example, I want to prevent other users from changing the width of the cells of a table. I understood that I need to turn on document protection for this, but I have no idea what I need to do next.

Comment: When protection is turned on, can you change the table? You should not be able to if you have selected any of the protection options beside "track changes".

Comment: OK, I redid a tutorial on this, and I managed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following [this tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/restrict-editing-to-secure-word-2010-document/) and it worked out. Basically, by default it completely locks the table and you can select the fields which can be edited. I don't know how to do advanced stuff, like locking only a part of the table, but, at this moment, I do not need this functionality.